# Unable to install amavisd-new on Ubuntu 16.10

Tags: postfix, amavisd-new

I am running Ubuntu 16.10 and trying to set up postfix. But my amavis installation is not happening smoothly.

```
apt upgrade
```

gives

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Setting up amavisd-new (1:2.10.1-4ubuntu1) ...
Creating/updating amavis user account...
Job for amavis.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
See "systemctl status amavis.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
invoke-rc.d: initscript amavis, action "start" failed.
amavis.service - LSB: Starts amavisd-new mailfilter
Loaded: loaded (/etc/init.d/amavis; generated; vendor preset: enabled
Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Mon 2016-11-14 19:56:05 IST; 9ms ago
Docs: man:systemd-sysv-generator(8)
Process: 5465 ExecStart=/etc/init.d/amavis start (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
Nov 14 19:56:05 lenovo amavis[5465]:   The value of variable $myhostname is...en
Nov 14 19:56:05 lenovo amavis[5465]:   a fully qualified domain name; perha...h.
Nov 14 19:56:05 lenovo amavis[5465]:   You must explicitly assign a FQDN of...me
Nov 14 19:56:05 lenovo amavis[5465]:   in /etc/amavis/conf.d/05-node_id, or...'s
Nov 14 19:56:05 lenovo amavis[5465]:   network name!
Nov 14 19:56:05 lenovo amavis[5465]: (failed).
Nov 14 19:56:05 lenovo systemd[1]: amavis.service: Control process exited, ...=1
Nov 14 19:56:05 lenovo systemd[1]: Failed to start LSB: Starts amavisd-new ...r.
Nov 14 19:56:05 lenovo systemd[1]: amavis.service: Unit entered failed state.
Nov 14 19:56:05 lenovo systemd[1]: amavis.service: Failed with result 'exit...'.
Hint: Some lines were ellipsized, use -l to show in full.
dpkg: error processing package amavisd-new (--configure):
subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
amavisd-new
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 8):

I had this issue, had to do with the FQDN of the server.

I modified the `/etc/amavis/conf.d/05-node_id` file.

I uncommented (removed the `#` before) `$myhostname = "....."` and inserted the FQDN.

Comment: Thx, never had this problem before. After i tried ten other things i came to this post and problem solved !

Comment: Thanks for the perfect answer. Helped me.

Comment: can somebody explain to me why should edit this file /etc/amavis/conf.d/05-node_id ? yes I know we may change something in there in order to solve this problem but what is specifically does ? what is the roll of $myhostname = "....." why should we changer it ?